# Convert jQuery to javascript (hide block after click on blank space)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello dear programmers Stack Overflow. I started to learn javascript and for a while (until you learn to write complex programs) would do without frameworks to understand the principles of the "native" code. I ran into the problem and found its realization ... but jQuery that difficult to understand deeper processes.

http://jsfiddle.net/P6YeA/25/

Can someone help analyze this example into its component? I would be extremely grateful for such a kind person help! :)
Sorry for the broken English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure JavaScript:

```
var toHide = document.getElementById('hideme');
var done = false;
document.onclick = function() {
    if(done) return;
    toHide.style.display = "none";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `.onclick` isn't idiomatic JS these days.

Comment: @Alnitak: true. I can never remember the exact name of the event-attaching method. Too used to jQuery.

Comment: I noticed a small bug - <a> links do not work (Firefox 15 and Google Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m). But I probably will correct itself later :) So thank you

Comment: Oh, I see what you were going for. I'd assumed your popup contained no links.